# Facebook icon randomly changes size on homescreen

Tags: home-screen

The facebook icon on the homescreen of my android tablet, version 4.2.2, keeps randomly changing size. Sometimes it's the same size as other icons, sometimes it appears much smaller than the rest, what's causing that?